# Why doesnt the javascript code appear in the input tag when a radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

The purpose of my JavaScript code is to have when the radio buttons are selected, they appear in the total input with when you miss a field and press submit, it gives you an alert prompting to fill out this specific field.

I have tried numerous times to debug the problems. But I can not decipher it. What is wrong with my code and how do I correct it?

```
 <div class="signup">       
        <form id="form1" name="form1" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
                <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="12" placeholder="First Name">

                <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" size="12" placeholder="Last Name">

                <label for="address">Address:</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="40" placeholder="Address">

                <label for="city">City:</label>
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="40" placeholder="City">

                <label for="state">State:</label>
                <input type="text" name="state" id="state" size="40" placeholder="State">

                <label for="country">Country:</label>
                <input type="text" name="country" id="country" size="40" placeholder="Country">

                <label for="zipcode">Zip Code:</label>
                <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code">

                <p><label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" placeholder="Email Address"></p>

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="20" placeholder="Password"> 

                <p><label for="repass">Retype Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="repass" id= "repass" size="20" placeholder="Re-type Password"></p>
            <p><b>Choose the Program you would like to purhase:</b></p>
            <table align ="center">
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="offers" value= "19.99" id="radio" onchange="ontotal()"></td>
        <td>Basic</td>
        <td>$<span >19.99</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="offers" value= "35.99" id="radio1" onchange="ontotal()" ></td>
        <td>Premium</td>
        <td>$<span >35.99</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="offers" value= "59.99" id="radio2" onchange="ontotal()"></td>
        <td>Super</td>
        <td>$<span>59.99</span></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
        Total:
        <input type="text" id="prototal" size="8" value="0" >
        </p>
        <button type="submit" onclick="doall()">Submit</button>
        <p id="sub"></p>
        </form>


        </div>


    function formval() {
    var first = document.getElementById("fname")
    var second = document.getElementById("lname")
    var third = document.getElementById("address")
    var fourth = document.getElementById("city")
    var fifth = document.getElementById("state")
    var sixth = document.getElementById("country")
    var seventh = document.getElementById("zipcode")
    var fire = document.getElementById("email")
    var sense = document.getElementById("password")
    var retype = document.getElementById("repass")

    if (first == ""){
        alert("Please enter first name");
        return false; 
    }
    if (second == ""){
        alert("Please enter last name");
        return false; 
    }
    if (third == ""){
        alert("Please enter address");
        return false; 
    }
    if(fourth == ""){
        alert("Please enter city");
        return false; 
    }
    if (fifth == ""){
        alert("Please enter state");
        return false; 
    }
    if (sixth == ""){
        alert("Please enter county");
        return false; 
    }
    if (seventh == ""){
        alert("Please enter zip code");
        return false; 
    }
    if (fire == ""){
        alert("Please enter email address");
        return false; 
    }
    if (sense == ""){
        alert("Please enter a password");
        return false; 
    }
    if (retype == ""){
        alert("Please enter your typed password");
        return false; 
    }
    else{
        alert("Thank you for submission. But don't forget to select a program to purchase.")
    }
    var sign = "Thank you for submission. Your purchase order instructions will be emailed shortly!";
    document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML = sign;
}
var programprices = new Array();
programprices["Basic"]=19.99;
programprices["Premium"]=35.99;
programprices["Super"]=59.99;

function ontotal(){
    var producttotal=0; 
    var calform = document.forms["form1"]
    var offers = calform.elements["offers"]
    for(var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) 
    {
        if (offers[i].checked)
        {
            producttotal = programprices[offers[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }
    return producttotal; 
}
function caltotal(){
    var price = ontotal;
    var presentme = document.getElementById('prototal')
    presentme.innerHTML = price
}
function doall(){
        formval();
        ontotal();
        caltotal();

}
var form = document.getElementById('form1');
    form.addEventListener('submit', formval());
    form.addEventListener('submit', ontotal());
    form.addEventListener('submit', caltotal());
```

Comment: `var first = document.getElementById("fname");` returns the element. You want the element's value: `var first = document.getElementById("fname").value;`

Comment: What do you mean return the element's value? I dont have a value associated to fname .

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form id="form1" onsubmit="submit()">

                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" maxlength="12" placeholder="First Name" required>

                <br>

                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" maxlength="12" placeholder="Last Name" required>

                <br>

                <label>Address:</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" maxlength="40" placeholder="Address" required>

                <br>

                <label>City:</label>
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" maxlength="40" placeholder="City" required>

                <br>

                <label>State:</label>
                <input type="text" name="state" id="state" maxlength="40" placeholder="State" required>

                <br>

                <label>Country:</label>
                <input type="text" name="country" id="country" maxlength="40" placeholder="Country" required>

                <br>

                <label>Zip Code:</label>
                <input type="number" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" required>

                <br>

                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" maxlength="30" placeholder="Email Address"required>

                <br>

                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password" required>

                <br>

                <label>Retype Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="repass" id= "repass" maxlength="20" placeholder="Re-type Password" required>

                <br>

                <p><b>Choose the Program you would like to purhase:</b></p>

                <input type="radio" value="19.99" onclick="calculate()" name="offers" id="offers1">$<span >19.99</span></input>

                <input type="radio" value="35.99" onclick="calculate()" name="offers" id="offers2">$<span >35.99</span></input>

                <input type="radio" value="59.99" onclick="calculate()" name="offers" id="offers3">$<span>59.99</span></input>

                <br><br>

                <strong>Total:</strong>
                <input type="text" id="prototal" ref="total" maxlength="8">

                <br><br>

               <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</form>



        function calculate()
        {
         if(document.getElementById('offers1').checked) 
             {
               document.getElementById('prototal').value = document.getElementById('offers1').value;
             }
             else if(document.getElementById('offers2').checked)   
             {
               document.getElementById('prototal').value = document.getElementById('offers2').value;
             }
             else if(document.getElementById('offers3').checked)   
             {
               document.getElementById('prototal').value = document.getElementById('offers3').value;
             }
             else
             {
               alert("Please Check any of the offers");
               return false;
             }
        } 

        function submit()
        {
          console.info("hello");
        }
```

Comment: @Futurevibez Dise this answer your question and serve the purpose CSS and styling can be done later

Comment: any luck this is what you required right @Futurevibez

Comment: if you share your email id I can send you the file

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code, it is difficult to address them all. I will point out the most obvious problems.

### JS arrays are not associative arrays

This code is incorrect:

```
var programprices = new Array();
programprices["Basic"]=19.99;
programprices["Premium"]=35.99;
programprices["Super"]=59.99;
```

Arrays in JS are not associative arrays. To do that in JS, you create an object with property names:

```
var programprices = {
    Basic: 19.99,
    Premium: 35.99,
    Super: 59.99
};
```

### Use of floating point values to represent monetary values

It is not a good idea to use floating point values to represent monetary values. You should either use strings instead of numbers, or scale the values up to the lowest unit of currency, such as cents.

If you simply need to submit a value in the post and won't need to do any mathematical operations on the value:

```
var programprices = {
    Basic: '19.99',
    Premium: '35.99',
    Super: '59.99'
};
```

OR, if you need to do mathematical operations on the prices, and your currency is something with 100 units per whole unit like cents:

```
var programprices = {
    Basic: 1999,
    Premium: 3599,
    Super: 5999
};
```

Integers can be represented exactly, tenths/etc cannot.

### Not passing sensible values to addEventListener

Your code to attach event handlers, *calls* the functions and passes their return value to `addEventListener`.

Replace this code:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', formval());
form.addEventListener('submit', ontotal());
form.addEventListener('submit', caltotal());
```

with this:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', formval);
form.addEventListener('submit', ontotal);
form.addEventListener('submit', caltotal);
```

Note that the functions themselves are passed to `addEventListener`, instead of calling the functions and passing their return values to `addEventListener`.

### Returning strange values from submit handler

Your `submit` handler is returning strange values. For example, the submit handler that calls ontotal gets the selected value returned to it. Event callbacks should not be returning strings or numbers.

### Assigning function to innerHTML

You assign a function to `presentme.innerHTML`. You probably wanted to call `ontotal`.

Replace this:

```
function caltotal(){
    var price = ontotal;
    var presentme = document.getElementById('prototal')
    presentme.innerHTML = price
}
```

with

```
function caltotal(){
    var price = ontotal();
    var presentme = document.getElementById('prototal')
    presentme.innerHTML = price;
}
```

### Overall style

Use of `onclick`, `onchange`, etc, is considered a bad practice. They require your handlers to be global. Global functions are not ideal. All of your variables are global as well. Any other errant script could clobber your variables or functions accidentally. You should scope your code in an IIFE to protect it from other code.

Your validation code does not actually stop the submit from proceeding. Your submit event handler should take a parameter, typically named `event` and it should call `event.preventDefault()` if it needs to stop the submit from proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var first = document.getElementById("fname")
```

assign the HTML element (in your case text field) into variable `test`. To assign the value of your text field into `first`,

```
var first = document.getElementById("fname").value
```

Comment: i run it on chrome but it does not return what I am trying to implement. The total value does not appear when the radio button is selected and it still does not alert me when Im missing a function

Answer (score 0):

Like Johnny said you're not getting the value of the elements, so you can use `.value` in the if statement like this:

```
if (first.value == ""){
    alert("Please enter first name");
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: When I do that, and run the page, it still prompts my var and else statements, nothing else. And my radio buttons still don't appear in the total input